# How do I make GWT cells in a CellTable always show as editable?

Tags: gwt, gwt2

By default, a GWT CellTable renders certain widgets (e.g. EditTextCell and DatePickerCell) to look like they're non-editable until you click on them. After you click on them, they're displayed as editable. When you click off, they go back to looking like they're read-only. I want all the fields to always appear editable by default, whether they're selected or not. Is there a way to do this?

BTW: I'm using GWT 2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sample best fit your needs **[Cell Sampler (showcase)](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r9101/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/cell/client/TextInputCell.ViewData.html)**

You should use [**TextInputCell**](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r9101/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/cell/client/TextInputCell.ViewData.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. That is exactly what I needed, I didn't see it before. BTW: the link to the Cell Sampler is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use `TextInputCell` instead of `EditTextCell` so text cells will look like form fields.
Extending `TextInputCell` with some copy-paste from `DatePickerCell` should do the trick for date cells.